# How long do I need to wait for my weapons to upgrade?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I finally found the components to upgrade my Engine Blade to Engine Blade III , so I headed to Cid to begin the upgrading. Of course I had to wait and was told I would be called when my weapon was finished

I did a few hunts and side quests, and I waited.... And I waited. And I waited some more. A few hours later and no call.

How long does it take for your weapons to upgrade? Does the wait time increase the more you upgrade?

Comment: Did you rest after all those quests?

Comment: @Isuka I rested once in that time frame. A majority of my time was in a dungeon, so I wonder if that somehow affected it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading [this guide](http://www.gosunoob.com/final-fantasy-xv/better-engine-blade-quest-ffxv/) about the quest you are in:

> Once you give Cid the material, the next step says: “Pass the time by undertaking quests and hunts”. To complete this step, you’ll have to rest for a couple of days in resting places. Once you are there, pay attention to the notification in the lower left corner. This is where you get the information on how many days have passed by.
>
> We needed a total of **five days** to get the call from Cid. Cid called to inform us that the quest is complete, and he is ready to give us an upgraded version of the weapon.

If you rest for this amount of time, you should end up getting this call from Cid, and finally get your Engine Blade II.

Now, for the other upgrades, reading [this answer](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/932981-final-fantasy-xv/74661943) from someone who upgraded them all, here is the number of hunts/quests you need to finish before going back to Cid to get those:

- Engine Blade III - One quest/hunt
- Ultima Blade - Three quests/hunts
- Drain Lance III - One quest/hunt
- Auto Crossbow Plus - Two quests/hunts
- Bioblaster Plus - Two quests/hunts
- Circular Saw Plus - Two quests/hunts
- Gravity Well Plus - Two quests/hunts
- Noiseblaster Plus - Two quests/hunts
- Drillbreaker Plus - Two quests/hunts
- Force Stealer II - One quest/hunt
- Plunderers II - One quest/hunt
- Valiant II - One quest/hunt
- Absorb Shield II - One quest/hunt

You will then have to rest one night before getting the call from Cid.

Comment: This appears to answer my question. Thanks for he swift response!

Comment: Additionally, you can o ly upgrade one at a time, despite how many components you have to give. And some weapons are only obtained by reading carrots to the gentleman who offers to by them near the end of the game.

Comment: The recent patch (1.03) allows you to upgrade multiple weapons with Cid at a time.

Comment: I believe you need to pass time and do hunts in Lucis, any hunts in Altissa don't count.